# how to change int to Binary value

Tags: python, symbolic-math

I have a problem changing my data into binary. It's not so complicated just using basic math; like if a = 60, then the result is "good", and when a >= 60, then it is "very good", but this is implemented in the data below:

[image: Screenshot]

This is my data; I want to change `new_cases` data to be binary value when the data >=1; I want the result to be 1, but when I use

```
Dt[Dt['new_cases'] >= 1 ] = 1
```

It doesn't work.

Please, is anyone able to run it? Any ideas? What could be causing this issue?

Thanks!

Comment: Please post a fully running small example script, plus what you want to happen. For instance, don't bother with columns that aren't part of the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to specify the column where you want to change the values:
`Dt.loc[Dt['new_cases'] >= 1, 'new_cases'] = 1`

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
Dt["new_cases"] = Dt["new_cases"].apply(lambda x: 1 if x >= 1 else 0)
```

OR

```
Dt["new_cases"] = 1
Dt.loc[Dt["new_cases"] < 1, "new_cases"] = 0
```